# Calculating density of $Y := c e^{-\alpha X}\chi_{\{X > 0\}}$

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions, density-function

> Suppose $X$ has a density $f_X$ and let $$Y := c e^{-\alpha
>  X}\chi_{\{X > 0\}}$$ for some $\alpha, c > 0$. Find $f_Y$ in terms of
>   $f_X$.

So let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded. We have $$\begin{align*} E(f(Y)) =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(c e^{-\alpha
 x}\chi_{\{x > 0\}}(x))f_X(x)dx \\
=& \int_{0}^\infty f(c e^{-\alpha
 x}\chi_{\{x > 0\}}(x))f_X(x)dx\\
&+\int_{-\infty}^0 f(c e^{-\alpha
 x}\chi_{\{x > 0\}}(x))f_X(x)dx\\
=& \int_{0}^\infty f(c e^{-\alpha
 x})f_X(x)dx\\
&+f(0)\int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(x)dx\\
=& \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^c \frac{f(s)}{s}f_X\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\log\frac{s}{c}\right)ds + f(0)\int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(x)dx
\end{align*}$$
As comparing with my book we should get $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{1}{y}f_X\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\log\frac{y}{c}\right) \chi_{(0,c)}(y)$$ which can be read off from the first term. However, what does happen with the second term? Does it just not appear in the density of $Y$ because $f(0)$ is constant?

Comment: What is $\chi$?

Comment: @QtizedQ The characteristic function.

Comment: @user365239 This is how one can calcukate densities: Taking an arbitrary measurable and bounded function $f$ and calculate the expectation of $f \circ X$.

Comment: The second term describes a Dirac measure at $y=0$ with mass $P(X\leqslant0)$. In particular, it corresponds to no PDF but to a discrete part of the distribution of $Y$.